# Throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, extends, throw

So, I have written some java code to find the lowest value of an array of integers. Unfortunately I cannot post the code as it's on a different PC, but its just simply sorting an array and printing out the element at 0. But I also need to write an exception class that should be thrown if the array does not contain any elements, however I don't know how to do this as I've never written an exception class before. Can anyone help please, a few people have told me to use the 'extends' keyword? but I also have no idea what that means.
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which programming language ?

Comment: One tip on writing and throwing custom exceptions: please include as much information in the message as possible (within reason of course). It might seem like extra work but it will be well worth it as soon as you (or the developers coming after you) have to debug the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is in Java (as you did not specify) you can define a new Exception class that way :

```
public class YourException extends Exception
{
    public YourException(String message)
    {
       super("error message");
    }
}
```

Then to throw it you would use `throw new YourException("error message");`